# Is there any API or firebase command to obtain a list of UUID's for iOS devices in Firebase App Distribution

Tags: firebase, firebase-app-distribution

We have a few cross-platform apps in development, for android setting up a CircleCI workflow to deploy to Firebase app distribution has been fairly straight forward, but for iOS I can't seem to find a good way to obtain the UUID for iOS testers that AppDistribution retrieves for us.

Is there any way to get a list of registered device UUID's?, I would rather not have to rely on parsing the email notifications.

Comment: Hi there, Did you figure it out? I am looking for a solution.